# Include files in eclipse build path?

Tags: eclipse, buildpath

I have few files excluded from build path in eclipse, by right clicking, build path and exclude from build path. Now I want to include those files again in build path. I am not able to find any option to include again. Any suggestion.

I am using Eclipse 3.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the project and select "Build Path.." -> Configure Build Path. Then you can include them in the appropriate tab (probably the "Source" tab).

Comment: Hmm, on hover over "Build Path.." I see "No actions available" in grey.  Why might that be?  I have one project open, and I'm right clicking on it's containing folder...